# Given $x_{n+1} = (-1/2) (x_n)^2 + x_n + 1$, show that $x_{2n}$ is always increasing and $x_{2n-1}$ is always decreasing.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given $x_{n+1} = (-1/2) (x_n)^2 + x_n + 1$, I have to show that $x_{2n}$ is always increasing and $x_{2n-1}$ is always decreasing.

I know that the sequence converges to $\sqrt{2}$ but I am unsure how to prove that the sequences are respectively monotonic.

Comment: Monotonicity depends on the starting point, too. Where $x_0$ is assumed to lie?

Comment: Anyway, assuming that $x_n=\sqrt{2}+t$, it follows that $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{2}\color{red}{-}(\sqrt{2}-1)t-\frac{t^2}{2}$, so if we start sufficiently close to $\sqrt{2}$, say on the right, then we go on the left, then back on the right and so on. If $|\sqrt{2}-x_n|$ is decreasing, there isn't much to prove.